# C fopen and fgets returning weird characters instead of file contents

Tags: c, io, fopen, fgets, cs50

I am doing a coding exercise and I need to open a data file that contains lots of data.  It's a .raw file.  Before I build my app I open the 'card.raw' file in a texteditor and in a hexeditor.  If you open it in textEdit you will see 'bit.ly/18gECvy ˇÿˇ‡JFIFHHˇ€Cˇ€Cˇ¿Vˇƒ' as the first line.  (The url points to Rick Roll as a joke by the professor.)

So I start building my app to open the same 'card.raw' file.  I'm doing initial checks to see the app print to the console the same "stuff" as when I open it with TextEdit.   Instead of printing out I see when I open it with TextEdit (see the text above), it starts and continues printing out text that looks like this:

\377\304 'u\204\206\226\262\302\3227\205\246\266\342GSc\224\225\245\265\305\306\325\326Wgs\244\346(w\345\362\366\207\264\304ǃ\223\227\2678H\247\250\343\344\365\377\304

Now I have no idea what the '\' and numbers are called (what do I search for to read more?), why it's printing that instead of the characters (unicode?) I see when I open in TextEdit, or if I can convert this output to hex or unicode.

My code is:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <limits.h>

    int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

        FILE* file;

        file = fopen("/Users/jamesgoldstein/CS50/CS50Week4/CS50Recovery/CS50Recovery/CS50Recovery/card.raw", "r");

        char output[LINE_MAX];

        if (file != NULL)
        {
            for (int i = 1; fgets(output, LINE_MAX, file) != NULL; i++)
            {
                printf("%s\n", output);
            }
        }

        fclose(file);

        return 0;
    }
```

**UPDATED & SIMPLIFIED CODE USING fread()**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    FILE* fp = fopen("/Users/jamesgoldstein/CS50/CS50Week4/CS50Recovery/CS50Recovery/CS50Recovery/card.raw", "rb");

    char output[256];

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Bad input\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 1; fread(output, sizeof(output), 1, fp) != NULL; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", output);
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Output is partially correct (here's a snippet of the beginning):

bit.ly/18gECvy

\377\330\377\340
\221\241\26145\301\321\341  "#&23DE\3616BFRTUe\202CVbdfrtv\222\242
'u\204\206\226\262\302\3227\205\246\266\342GSc\224\225\245\265\305\306\325\326Wgs\244\346(w\345\362\366\207\264\304ǃ\223\227\2678H\247\250\343\344\365\377\304
=\311\345\264\352\354   7\222\315\306\324+\342\364\273\274\205$z\262\313g-\343wl\306\375My:}\242o\210\377
3(\266l\356\307T饢"2\377
\267\212ǑP\2218 \344

**Actual card.raw file snippet of beginning**

bit.ly/18gECvy ˇÿˇ‡JFIFHHˇ€Cˇ€Cˇ¿Vˇƒ
ˇƒÖ
    !1AQa$%qÅë°±45¡—·  "#&23DEÒ6BFRTUeÇCVbdfrtví¢

Comment: They look like escape sequences for special characters

Comment: Also, because this is a `.rtf` file, it is going to be weird. don't use textedit to verify the file contents as it will be converting the raw .rtf data into presentable info.  Open terminal and `cat /Users/jamesgoldstein/CS50/CS50Week4/CS50Recovery/CS50Recovery/CS50Recovery/test.rtf` and you should see the same thing your program does

Comment: The .rtf file was a test, the actual file is .raw.  I just corrected the code.

Comment: What does `od -b /Users/jamesgoldstein/CS50/CS50Week4/CS50Recovery/CS50Recovery/CS50Recovery/card.raw` show you? (maybe pipe it via `less`). If the values match your output, then your program is behaving correctly, I think; the "\xxx" are octal escape sequences.

Comment: if the file contents is a JPEG image, then suggest googling for the format of a JPEG image and using that info to decode each field in the file into something printable that you can understand.

Comment: in the modified question, posted code, this line: `for (int i = 1; fread(output, sizeof(output), 1, fp) != NULL; i++)` is a bit iffy as the variable `i` is never used.  Suggest: `while( fread(output, sizeof(output), 1, fp) )`  as it will do the same thing, without the extraneous variable `i`  And if (as one answer suggest) reading the whole file in one 'gulp' then even the `while` would not be needed.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should open the .raw file in the mode `"rb"`.
Then use `fread()`

Comment: Ok, much closer!  Got some of the file to come through and some to come through as /###/###/####.

Comment: @JamesGoldstein `fread` doesn't give you a string. You can't just pass it to `printf` `%s`.

Comment: Hi. I really don't know how to tell you exactly what is the problem. But I will tell what I think you should probably check: **a)** Is the .raw file using the same character enconding(UTF-8, Unicode, etc.) **b)** Pay attention that strings in C have the NULL terminator '\0'. If you have any new results edit and let us know. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use `fread` rather than `fgets`, since the latter is really designed for reading text files, and this is clearly not a text file.

Your updated code in fact does have the very problem I originally wrote about (but have since retracted), since you are now using `fread` rather than `fgets`:

```
for (int i = 1; fread(output, sizeof(output), 1, fp) != NULL; i++)
{
    printf("%s\n", output);
}
```

I.e. you are printing the `output` buffer as if it were a null-terminated string, when in fact it is not. Better to use `fwrite` to `STDOUT`.

However, I think the essence of the problem here is trying to display arbitrary bytes (which don't actually represent a character string) to the terminal. The terminal may interpret some byte sequences as commands which affect what you see. Also, `textEdit` may determine that the file is in some character encoding and decode characters accordingly.

> Now I have no idea what the '\' and numbers are called (what do I search for to read more?)

They look like octal escape sequences to me.

> why it's printing that instead of the characters (unicode?)

It's nothing to do with unicode. Maybe it's your terminal emulator deciding that those characters are unprintable, and so replacing them with an escape sequence.

In short, I think that your method (comparing visually what you see in a text editor with what you see on the terminal) is flawed. The code you have to read from the file looks correct; I'd suggest proceeding with the exercise and checking results then, or if you really want to be sure, look at the file using a hex editor, and have your program output the byte values it reads (as numbers) - and compare those with what you see in the hex editor.

Comment: `fgets` is fine.  It adds a terminating null byte.  In fact, `fgets` is a standard way to read text files line-by-line.

Comment: @Alok-- you're right of course. I mis-remembered. I've edited that part out but might just delete the answer shortly.

Comment: @Alok-- (except of course that the file is _not_ a text file, and is not necessarily in lines, and the updated code uses `fread` rather than `fgets` and so _is_ subject to the problem. I have edited accordingly).

Answer (score 1):

From the presence of the string `"JFIF"` in the first line of the file `card.raw` ("bit.ly/18gECvy ˇÿˇ‡JFIFHHˇ€Cˇ€Cˇ¿Vˇƒ") it seems like `card.raw` is a JPEG image format file that had the bit.ly URL inserted at its beginning.

You are going to see weird/special characters in this case because it is not a usual text file at all.

Also, as davmac pointed out, the way you are using `fgets` isn't appropriate even if you were dealing with an actual text file.  When dealing with plain text files in C, the best way is to read the entire file at once instead of line by line, assuming sufficient memory is available:

```
size_t f_len, f_actualread;

char *buffer = NULL;

fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END)
f_len = ftell(fp);
rewind(fp);

buffer = malloc(f_len + 1);

if(buffer == NULL)
{
    puts("malloc failed");
    return;
}

f_actualread = fread(buffer, 1, f_len, file);
buffer[f_actualread] = 0;

printf("%s\n", output);

free(buffer);
buffer = NULL;
```

This way, you don't need to worry about line lengths or anything like that.

Comment: Actually, `fgets` is fine to read text files.  It always null-terminates the data.

Comment: @Alok-- I think the point here was that is _isn't_ a text file.

Comment: @Alok-- Late reply but I was specifically referring to "the way [OP] was using `fgets`"